# Image not uploading into mysql database php

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am trying to upload an image by updating MySQL table column with the image location.

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_POST['upload']))
{
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "root", "rental");

if($link == false){ 
    die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
$image = $_FILES['propic']['tmp_name'];
$propic = addslashes(file_get_contents($image));
$lipic = "img/user.png";
$aadhar="img/user.png";
$sql= "UPDATE profiles SET profilepic='$propic', license='$lipic', aadhar='$aadhar' WHERE email='".$_SESSION['email']."'";
$result=mysqli_query($link,$sql);
}   
?>
```

HTML Code:

```
<form id="form" method="post" action="profile.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <input type="file" name="propic" accept="image/*">
 <input type="file" name="lipic" accept="image/*">
 <input type="file" name="aapic" accept="image/*">
 <input type="submit" class="mybutton myfont" name="upload" value="Submit" style="width:100px; background-color:black;">
 </form>
```

MySQL table

[image]

Comment: Please check this link : https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp

Comment: You cannot upload a file to varchar database, you upload the file into the directory files, [here example](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp)

Comment: Please also look into this to not get you website hacked: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php

Comment: _"by updating MySQL table column with the image location"_ - `$propic` contains the image content, not the image location.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. You are missing file uploading code.

```
$image = $_FILES['propic']['tmp_name'];
$name = "img/$_FILES['propic']['name']";
move_uploaded_file($image, $name); //Here you have to upload a file in a folder.
```

This is just for a reference. Use this and you will be able to upload a file on server.

Comment: However, this won't help the OP with the actual issue in the question.

Comment: After moving the image to the directory, how can I store the location of the image in my database.

Comment: You just have to store image name. Although I strongly recommend to use timestamp while creating image name, so you don't override existing image in the folder. Create unique name, move image to folder and save the name in you db.